# gnome overvew on second monitor - how to turn it off

Tags: gnome, super-key

Is there a way to turn off overview (zooming) on second monitor.
When I hit supperKey I want to have an overview on my main monitor but I do not want the second monitor to resize go to overview mode.
Is there any way to turn it off?